# How Can I mass delete Account Records with a specific Record Type in Salesforce using Workbench?

Tags: api, bulk-api, delete, workbench

I tried to delete Account Records using workbench and it gives me this error:

> Failed: InvalidBatch : Referenced file "request.txt" is missing or is a directory

I am not able to understand how to create "request.txt" and what my zip file should include. As in, my Zip file should include csv file containing Ids of the Account records that I want to delete or every records itself?

Comment: You don't need to provide any zip file, you can select the csv file directly while deleting, which has all the ids of the records to be deleted

Comment: I have tried that, but it gives me error "The file uploaded is too large. Please try again. (Error 1)". So I tried with the zipped file. @HemantJain

Answer (score 1):

First of you need to export a .csv file with extract of Account records only with Ids as follows

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Recordtype.Name='<your recordtype name>';
```

Then from workbench select the .csv and proceed with Delete

[image: delete]

Here to delete from file, the file should be either .csv or .xml-formatted manifest called request.txt.

May be you didn't select correct file that's why the error is.

**Update**

I think workbench can process max 50,000 records in a csv.

It is recommended to use Dataloader for this kind of deletion process.

Comment: I added proper .csv file but its shows error "The file uploaded is too large. Please try again. (Error 1)"

Comment: how many records are there in the file? whats the size of the file?

Comment: Total Records are - 170735 file size - 3,335 kb

Comment: why don't to use dataloader?

Comment: So, it is not Possible from Workbench?

Comment: You just a create files with recordId max 50000 records and process from workbench

Comment: Ok, Thanks for this information. But I still want to know why there is option of adding a Zip file with "request.txt", where and when it is used?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by renaming my CSV data file to: request.txt
The file contains ID's to delete.
The file is zipped and uploaded to workbench.

The job ran okay, but I hit a limit on how many records I could process (this is a partial-org).